# Using array_filter to filter multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, the second is multidimensional. I'm trying to return a third array where the host_id in Array2 match the values in Array1.

```
Array1 
(
    [0] => 146
    [1] => 173
)

Array2
(
    'localhost' => (
        '0' => (
            'host_id' => 146
        ),
    ),
    '192.168.0.43' => (
        '1' => (
            'host_id' => 160
        ),
    ),
    '192.168.0.38' => (
        '2' => (
            'host_id' => 173
        )
    )
)
```

So Array3 should be:

```
    Array3
    (
        [localhost] => Array
            '0' => (
                'host_id' => 146
            ),

        [192.168.0.38] => Array
            '0' => (
                'host_id' => 173
            ),

    )
```

I have tried this, but it's only returning the last matched host_id.

```
foreach ($Array1 as $value) {   

    $filtered_hosts = array_filter($Array2, function ($host) use ($value) {

        return in_array($host['host_id'], $host_id);
    });
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you're overwriting `$filtered_hosts` in foreach... you want to push to $filtered_hosts instead

Comment: Hi a better solution would be to use with `array_filter`, [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Try it out.

Comment: Thanks ankabout, changing my return statement to this solved my problem.

return in_array($host['host_id'], $value);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) without the `foreach`.

Pass the first array to `use($array1)` and use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the value for 'host_id' exists.

```
$array1 = [
  146,
  173
];

$array2 = [
    'localhost' => [
        'host_id' => 146
    ],
    '192.168.0.43' => [
        'host_id' => 160
    ],
    '192.168.0.38' => [
        'host_id' => 173
    ]
];

$filtered_hosts = array_filter($array2, function($x) use ($array1) {
    return in_array($x['host_id'], $array1);
});


print_r($filtered_hosts);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/e3bQN)

**Update**

For the updated data structure you could get the first item from the subarray with for example [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

```
$filtered_hosts = array_filter($array2, function ($x) use ($array1) {
    return in_array(reset($x)['host_id'], $array1);
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/NFNfj)

Comment: Thanks, changing my return statement to use in_array gave me the desired result.

Comment: What if you add another dimension to the array?

$Array2 = [
    'localhost' => [
        '0' => [
            'host_id' => 146
        ],
    ],
    '192.168.0.43' => [
        '1' => [
            'host_id' => 160
        ],
    ],
    '192.168.0.38' => [
        '2' => [
            'host_id' => 173
        ]
    ]
];

Comment: @JoshForcier You have changed your original question. Do you mean like this https://3v4l.org/AMHda